# phpmyadmin shows 8 rows but only the 1st is displayed on the page

Tags: php, html

```
<h5>Student-sem</h5>
<p> 
     <select required>";
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <?php 
            $query = "SELECT distinct `sem_no` FROM `course`,`student_info` WHERE course.c_id=student_info.c_id and `s_id` = '$s_id' ORDER BY `sem_no`";
            if($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
                 while ($arow = mysql_fetch_array($query_run)){
                     $asem = $arow['sem_no'];
                     echo "<option >" .$asem. "</option>" ;
                 }
            }
            else{
                echo mysql_error();
            }
          ?>
    </select>
</p>
```

the query returns 8 values in phpmyadmin bt only the 1st value is displayed with this code

Comment: the query returns 8 values in phpmyadmin bt  only the 1st value is displayed with this code..

Comment: There's a rogue `";` in your code which wouldn't cause this problem, but might suggest you didn't simply copy and paste the code. Is what you've posted EXACTLY what's in your PHP file?

Comment: Are you sure the value `$s_id` contains what you think it does?  `var_dump` it before your query, then re-run your query in phpmyadmin with that value to see if you get the same results

Comment: Good point. `echo $query=`... and see if it's what you expect.

Comment: ahhh done there was login issue problem.. thank u for your comment

Comment: btw i dont know how to grab the selected value to run another query  can u gauyz help me ???